# Validar un campo de texto dentro de dos div

Tags: javascript, html

¿Como podria validar un formulario?

Ya intenté esto y nada.

**HTML**

```
<form class="login-form">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario" name="User">

    </div>
    <div class="form-group log-Pass">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" name="Password">
    </div>
    <span class="alert">Datos Erroneos</span>
    <a class="link" href="#">¿Olvidaste tu contraseña?</a>
    <button type="button" class="log-btn" onClick="login()">Entrar</button>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function login() {
    var usuario = document.login - form.User.value;
    var contraseña = document.login - form.Password.value;
    if (usuario == "root" && contraseña = "123") {
        alert("Logeado");
    } else {
        alert("Datos erroneos");
    }
}
```

Comment: Y algo mas estas fallando en lo sgte; en tu javascript haces referencia a la clase login - form de tu formulario el  javascript no va a reconocer ese lemento por eso es que lo quite en mi respuesta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el `if (usuario == "root" && contraseña = "123")` estas asignando a contraseña el valor de 123 en vez de comparar con 123 ===

Answer (score 2):

¿Porque tratas de validar datos en el front-end? , es mejor hacerlo desde el back-end , el error esta, en que **estas asignando** en lugar de comparar.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es por la letra ñ ya que javascript  no lo encuentra parte de un identificador de variable para que te acepte ponle en el meta este codigo  y tambien ponle un name al formulario ,

Este es tu ejemplo y si me funciona

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"   integrity="sha256-slogkvB1K3VOkzAI8QITxV3VzpOnkeNVsKvtkYLMjfk="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">

</script>
</head>
<body>

<form class="form" action="index.php" method="POST" name="form">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="user" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario" >

    </div>
    <div class="form-group log-Pass">
        <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" >
    </div>
    <span class="alert">Datos Erroneos</span>
    <a class="link" href="#">¿Olvidaste tu contraseña?</a>
    <button type="button" class="log-btn" onClick="login()">Entrar</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function login() {
    var usuario = document.form.user.value;
    var contraseña = document.form.password.value;
        if (usuario == "root" && contraseña == "123") {
        alert("Logeado");
    } else {
        alert("Datos erroneos");
    }
    }
</script>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]